# How to combine (concatenate) JSON objects which contain a common key name but unique values in jq

Tags: json, jq

Using the **[jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)** command, I am trying to transform some data into a specific format

I have a sample JSON set:

- ```
  {
    "site": [
      {
        "uuid": "23451fae-a14f-49d1-a096-8f033f69dc80",
        "testtype": "Scheduled",
        "name": "JANE DOE HEAD OFFICE",
        "equip": "Unique Item One"
      }
    ]
  }
  {
    "site": [
      {
        "uuid": "23451fae-a14f-49d1-a096-8f033f69dc80",
        "testtype": "Scheduled",
        "name": "JANE DOE HEAD OFFICE",
        "equip": "Unique Item Two"
      }
    ]
  }
  {
    "site": [
      {
        "uuid": "23451fae-a14f-49d1-a096-8f033f69dc80",
        "testtype": "Scheduled",
        "name": "JANE DOE HEAD OFFICE",
        "equip": "Unique Item Three"
      }
    ]
  }
  ```

I want to extract the ***unique*** values (**`equip`**);

- From known locations with ***common*** names in the data set (**`site`**); **and**
- Have the values concatenated with a ***string*** delimiter that I can change;
- In order to get an output like this: (shown with a **`comma`** as my choice of delimiter):

- ```
  {
    "site": [
      {
        "uuid": "23451fae-a14f-49d1-a096-8f033f69dc80",
        "testtype": "Scheduled",
        "name": "JANE DOE HEAD OFFICE",
        "equip": "\"Unique Item One\",\"Unique Item Two\",\"Unique Item Three\""
      }
    ]
  }
  ```

---

Just addressing the `equip` value as a first step; some of the command combinations I've tried using the sample dataset (cropping the output to the first k:v pair on each):

- Trying the **-j** flag: (Problem: *Tailing* comma)

  ```
  jq -jr '.site[].equip | . + ","' 

  Unique Item One,Unique Item Two,Unique Item Three,
  ```

- Using ***Reduce*** (Problem: *Leading* comma)

  ```
  jq -j '.site[].equip | reduce . as $item (""; "" + "," + ($item))'

  ,Unique Item One,Unique Item Two,Unique Item Three
  ```
- Using ***join()***: (Problem: Not used properly so no `comma` at all)

  ```
  jq '.site | map(.equip) | join(",")'

  "Unique Item One"
  "Unique Item Two"
  "Unique Item Three"
  ```

- Using ***@csv***: (Problem: *trailing* `comma`, and not even from @csv)

  ```
  jq -rj '.site[].equip + "," | [.] | @csv'

  "Unique Item One,""Unique Item Two,""Unique Item Three,"
  ```

Other things I've tried result in a leading comma, or concatenating and stringifying every single object recursively, but I have come to the conclusion that I'm fundamentally looking at this wrong.

- If I bring in **external** input for testing, (In this case passing ***--arg***) I can get close enough to the desired result to progress further, using *assignment operators*, but it still produces a line for each result, and is getting very inflexible:
- ```
  jq -c --arg new2 "Unique Item Two" --arg new3 "Unique Item Three" -r '.site[] |= .equip + "," + $new2 + "," + $new3 | add | .[] | tojson'

  "Unique Item One,Unique Item Two,Unique Item Three"
  ```

Now I'm not sure if I'm missing something simple or if this requires some complex counting and iteration.

**Note:** I know how easy it would be to cut the output up externally - there are certain reasons that I want to do this entirely in **jq**, as it's really the structure I am trying to get right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could group them up to determine what `equip` values need to be combined, then you could build up your string.

```
$ jq -n --arg delim ',' '{
    site: [inputs.site[]]
        | group_by(.uuid)
        | map({
            uuid: .[0].uuid,
            testtype: .[0].testtype,
            name: .[0].name,
            equip: (map(.equip | tojson) | unique | join($delim))
        })
}' input.json
```

This produces: (note: the item order is not necessarily preserved)

```
{
  "site": [
    {
      "uuid": "23451fae-a14f-49d1-a096-8f033f69dc80",
      "testtype": "Scheduled",
      "name": "JANE DOE HEAD OFFICE",
      "equip": "\"Unique Item One\",\"Unique Item Two\",\"Unique Item Three\""
    }
  ]
}
```

If the string is meant to look like csv data and needs escaping, be sure to do so.  Assuming quotes need to be escaped, you could modify this part:

```
map(.equip | gsub("\"";"\"\"") |  tojson)
```